# Best practice to organize data on new two drive PC

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, disk-management

I recently bought a pre-built new desktop PC and have a little question about how to organize data.

The desktop has a 256GB SSD labelled as "Windows" C: drive, and has Windows 10 installed on it. There is also an 7200RPM 1TB HDD, labelled as "DATA" D: drive, and on this same HDD there is a OEM partition labelled as "RECOVERY" of 17.34GB (guessing this is a Windows recovery thing).

When I install new software/program/game, it goes by default on the C: drive(SSD). I already installed a few programs on it, but now I wonder what the best practic(s) is(are) for installation in a two-drive Windows system such as this.

Should I change the default path so all new programs install on the 1TB HDD D: drive instead? Because as of now, everything, including downloads, seem to go to the SSD drive, and since its only 256GB it will end up to be full at some point. Also, I don't see why the D: 1TB drive is there, if nothing will go on it.

What's the best practice to follow?

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat a matter of opinion.

But the way I would choose to do it is to put all programs and system files on C: and all my data on D:.

You want the speed of the SSD for the operating system and related files and for your programs to open quickly. The hard drive is good for your data where you don’t particularly need a lot of speed.

To do so, all you really have to do is relocate your user data folders to the D: drive. First, make a folder on the D: drive called something like `data` then open file explorer to your user profile folder by navigating to `C:\users\<your username>`. Then drag and drop the data folders (documents, pictures, movies, music, downloads, etc.) to the folder you put on the D: drive. Windows will ask if you want to move your data to the new location and you can answer positively.

Now your data will be on D: and you can continue to install programs on C: without much worry of filling the SSD. The data folders have been “redirected” and the built in links to Documents, Pictures, etc. will continue to function as normal.

And, most importantly, don’t forget to back up your data.

Comment: Wouldn't it depend on the type of data?  System and application software files would load faster, but that tends to be a one-time thing.  If you are engaging in activity that is continuously referencing or updating stored data, that might give you more benefit by speeding up your work.  I'm wondering how useful a generic answer can be.